# Is there a way to get the number of the user's unsubscribed friends?

Tags: facebook, subscription

That's what I need, to get the user's (with an Access Token of course) unsubscribed friends? I'd be great to get an array with all the users, but a simple count would do the job.

I see here that natively Facebook provides this option: In the main page, the Newsfeed option has an Edit button, there you can see the number of unsubscribed friends, no way that it's in the API?

We can access this setting on frontend by going to "News Feed" > "Edit Settings" then we get "Hide posts from" with the listing and the count. Can I access this data via API?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by accessing the "user_subscriptions" and "friends", using an access token, and removing the "user_subscriptions" results from the "friends" results so you are left with the friends that are unsubscribed.

I don't think facebook offers a parameter to get unsubscibed friends on its own.

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work. Idk if I'm doing something wrong, but "me/subscribedto" or "me/subscribees" returns an integer value that I believe that are the users I'm subscibed to that are not my friends (my result for exemple was the number 1), and "me/subscribers" returns the users that subscribe to my profile. 
I tried it here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer and saw the references here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/638/

Thanks again :)

Comment: I think by being friends with someone you are not subscribed to them anymore, as they are friends back. You are only subscribed to someone if you choose to be and they haven't added you as a friend.Do you mean friends that have deselected "show in news feed"? as I don't think you have access to this.

Comment: Yeah, there is an explicit option that is "Unsubscribe" from friends, I'd like to have this count, but now I'm starting to think it's impossible. Too bad, thanks anyway!